# concatenate column values in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have a csv file with two columns:

```
  col1   col2
 ----- | -----
  link1  unix=number1  
  link2  unix=number2  
  link3  unix=number3
```

**What I need:**

I need to concatenate each value in col1 with each value in col2 to have the following result:

```
ecol1   col2           col3
----- | -----      |   ----
 link1  unix=number1  link1unix=number1
 link2  unix=number2  link1unix=number2
 link3  unix=number2  link1unix=number3
 link4  NAN           link2unix=number1
 link5  NAN           link2unix=number2
 link6  NAN           link2unix=number3
                      etc ..
```

This is my code and it is not working:

```
i = 0
while True:
  df= pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=lambda x: x in range(0,i))
  for i, row in df.iterrows():  
    row = df['col1'] + df['col2']
    i+=1
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import itertools
df['col3']=[''.join(i) for i in list(itertools.product(df['col1'],df['col2']))]
```

EDIT:

```
l= [''.join(i) for i in list(itertools.product(df1.col1,df1.col2))]
df=df.reindex(range(len(l)))
df['col3']=l
print(df)

  col1 col2 col3
0    a    x   ax
1    b    y   ay
2    c    z   az
3  NaN  NaN   bx
4  NaN  NaN   by
5  NaN  NaN   bz
6  NaN  NaN   cx
7  NaN  NaN   cy
8  NaN  NaN   cz
```

Comment: Col2 is a number, will it make a difference?

Comment: yes it will, use `[''.join(i) for i in list(itertools.product(df['col1'].astype(str),df['col2'].astype(str)))]`

Comment: giving me `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` - I modified the length of both columns so they can be the same length of index but it is still not working.

Comment: Yes if you dont have any data below it will, how do you want to fill the data by NAN?

Comment: @J.Doe check EDIT section

Comment: I just edited the table in my question, can you please take a look?